# can't find the xml file in the included file

Tags: php

the folder hierarchy is:

```
phpproject:
  config.php
  admin.xml
  crimes:
    addcrime.php
```

contents of addcrime.php is:

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `crime` (`crime_name`,`crime_type`  ) VALUES(          '{$_POST['crime_name']}','{$_POST['crime_type']}'  ) ";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Added row.<br />";
echo "<a href='list.php'>Back To Listing</a>";
```

}
?>

**Crime Name:**

**Crime Type:**

contents of config.php:

if (file_exists("./admin.xml")) {

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("./admin.xml");


$uid = trim($xml->name);

$pwd = trim($xml->password);
$db = trim($xml->dbname);

echo $uid;
echo $pwd;

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', $uid, $pwd);
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}


$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use : ' . $db . ' ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "<h2> Database " . $db . " selected successfully " . "</h2> <br/>";
    echo "<h2> Username:" . $uid . "</h2> <br/>";
}
```

} else {

```
echo "file not found";
```

}
?>

the config.php file is not able to find the admin.xml which is in the same folder

Comment: Use the full path to the file.

Comment: Try: `if (file_exists("admin.xml"))`.

Comment: Your code runs in the context of `addcrime.php`, so naturally the file is located at `../admin.xml` from there … absolute basics, dude!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what @CBroe said in his comment. What you might want to try is:

`if (file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'admin.xml'))`